# Automatically add new category in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Is it possible at the time of installation of the component automatically add a link in the menu on the component? In the moment i am using a hardcore method via sql code execution on instal, but in the future in my case could be some problems with id's

Comment: are you using joomla 1.5 or older version

Comment: What menu item do you want to add, exactly? Do you mean the menu in the administration interface, or a menu on the front-end (i.e. the actual website)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the answer is yes. You can absolutely add code to do basically what ever you want during the install process.

However, this is an insanely bad idea and very likely to get people to not use your extension. The problem with automatically adding a menu is that you have no way of knowing if you are completely screwing up someone's site by adding a new menu item where it shouldn't appear.

You are better off creating good documentation that explains exactly what needs to be done with the menu item.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, but i am only developer - the "it head" is boss... Right from the start of the project i was completely against using Joomla, but as boss said - customers underpays, if herds Joomla so now i have a lot of hardcode to do. At the moment i am writing a big SQL with plenty of JOIN's to avoid all possible duplications.

Comment: Duplication is only one of the issues though. If you are adding a new menu item, the menu you add it to might not have the room for another item and break the layout, the menu might be in the wrong module position, all kinds of stuff. You will also have the issue of what modules are assigned to that menu item. It would be nearly impossible to account for all of the possibilities when it comes to a new menu item and the problems it might cause.

Comment: i am just adding copy of existing row - what could be wrong on the default template?